How to remove link highlighting in SwiftUI TextField?
In SwiftUI TextField, how to remove link auto highlighting? Its is showing link in blue color, but I want to make the placeholder the default gray for the text field.
TextField("https://example.com", text: $name)


I tried the following but did not work.
TextField("https://example.com", text: $name)
    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 8, bottom: 8, trailing: 8))
    .background(.clear)
    .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
    .autocorrectionDisabled(true)

